# How to bust out of bash terminal in Emacs

Tags: bash, emacs

I may have gotten myself in a bind. I have 3 windows in emacs, 2 of which are buffers and one of which is a bash shell that I created using: `M-x term`

Now I can't switch out of that window (`C-x o`) because all the commands are being directed to the terminal. How do I switch in an out of this buffer window?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I typically use `M-x shell` to launch a shell rather than `term`.

Try switching between "line mode" and "char mode" using `C-c C-j` and `C-c C-k` as described in the documentation for term mode.

Answer (score 4):

Press `C-c o` instead of `C-x o` to switch to another window. Press `C-c b` instead of `C-x b` to switch to another buffer. More generally, use the prefix `C-c` where you would normally use `C-x`. Press `C-c C-h` to see the full list of commands available on the `C-c` prefix. There is in particular `C-c M-x` to execute a command by name (normally on `M-x`).

Most control keys are sent to the application, and in particular help is not available on `C-h`, but it's still available on `f1`, so you can press `f1 m` to see the help for Term mode, `f1 w` to see on what keys a command is bound and so on.

If you exit the shell (by typing `C-d` or with the `exit` command), the normal Emacs bindings are restored.